# How create 3d object into a web page and move it?

Tags: javascript, html, three.js, blender

I'm a newbie and excuse me for my english. There is my problem :
I would like to realize a web page (using HTML5) with an area in which there is a plane ( in 3D ) and it is possible to make it fly , move etc .. , always within this area. I want to know how can I make this happen ? I read that this is possible using Three.js , but what about the creation of the object and the movement? I read for example about the software Blender for the creation of the 3d object, but once created the object in 3D , how can I import it on the page and move it with the mouse ( or keyboard ) ?
I repeat , I'm a newbie , maybe it will seem a silly question , but I would some advice to understand where I should start.
Thank you very much for your attention

Comment: I'm not familiar with three.js, but it looks like you could export your Blender object to an .OBJ file and then use [the OBJ loader](http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Loaders/OBJLoader) to load and parse it.

Answer (score 0):

To create a simple plan, you don't have to create a 3D-model. There is a simpler way to do this but first you have to create a 3D scene, with a camera and renderer. Additionally you have to add a `<div>` tag to your page to render the scene in it.

Add to HTML:

```
<div id="scene" style="width:1000px; height:500px"></div>
```

JS could look like this:

```
var mountElem = document.getElementById('scene');
var width = mountElem.innerWidth;
var height = mountElem.innerHeight;

function createScene() {
    var scene = new THREE.Scene();
    var camera = getNewCamera(scene.position);
    var renderer = getNewRenderer();

    // Add plane
    var white = 0xffffff;
    var plane = getNewPlane(100, 100, white);
    scene.add(plane);

    renderScene(renderer, scene, camera);
}

function getNewCamera(lookAtPos) {
    var viewPort = 45;
    var near = 0.1;
    var far = 10000;
    var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera(viewPort, width / height, near, far);

    // Set initial position position
    camera.position.set(0, 50, 200);
    camera.lookAt(lookAtPos);

    return camera;
}

function getNewRenderer() {
    var sceneBackgroundColor = 0xaaaaff;
    var alpha = 1;
    var renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
    renderer.setSize(width, height);
    renderer.setClearColor(sceneBackgroundColor, alpha);

    return renderer;
}

function getNewPlane(planeWidth, planeHeight, color) {
    var geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(planeWidth, planeHeight, 1, 1);
    var material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: color, side: THREE.DoubleSide });
    var plane = new THREE.Mesh(geometry, material);
    plane.position.set(0, 0, 0);

    return plane;
}

function renderScene(renderer, scene, camera) {
    mountElem.appendChild(renderer.domElement);
    render(renderer, scene, camera);
}

function render(renderer, scene, camera) {
    requestAnimationFrame(function() { render(renderer, scene, camera); });
    renderer.render(scene, camera);
}
```

Move a object/plane like this:

```
plane.position.x += movementX;
plane.position.y += movementY;
plane.position.z += movementZ;
```

You could apply a `mousemove` event on the `<div>` and put the above movement code into that event-function. `movementX/Y/Z` would be the movement of the mouse.

Hope that helped.